# upload file to web method

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net

I'm using dropzonejs to upload file.
I would like to send a file to web method.

```
     $("#dropzonejs-example").dropzone({
                    url: '<%= ResolveUrl("MyPage.aspx/SaveDocument")%>',
                    maxFilesize: 1, // MB                      
                    addRemoveLinks: true,
                    dictResponseError: "Can't upload file!",
                    autoProcessQueue: false,

                    init: function () {
                        var submitButton = document.querySelector("#btnUpload")
                        myDropzone = this; // closure

                        submitButton.addEventListener("click", function () {
                            myDropzone.processQueue();
                        }, false);
                        this.on("addedfile", function () {
                        });
                    }
                }); 




    [WebMethod]
    public static bool SaveDocument()
    {
       //
        return true;
    }
```

My problem is that I don't know how to reach web method.
When I try upload a file in response I get html code of my website...

Can someone show me an example how web method should look like?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: I think you want to fetch it from `Request.Files`  http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httprequest.files(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: I would suggest using `ashx handler` for this, reason - when you invoke webmethod, you might need to pass param or post file using `FormData`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Problem is the content type dropzonejs is sending. 
**Multipart/form-data** is not allowed to accept by web method.